# JQueryUI Dialog displays on refreshing browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an ASP.NET application written with C# server side code. When I refresh the browser the JQueryUI dialog shows up even though it should not be showing up.

The issue is i need to create the content of the DIV being shown as dialog in the server side code.

After I create the content I post the script to the browser using the RegisterStartupScript method and JavaScript function below:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup();", true);

  function ShowPopup() {
              $("#dialog-modal").dialog({                 
                  height: 330,
                  width: 700,
                  modal: true, resizable: false,                          
                  buttons: {
                      Close: function () {
                          $(this).dialog('close');
                      }
                  }                
              });               
          };

 <div id="dialog-modal" title='Message Preview' style="display: none;"> 
         <br />       
         <div style="width:100%">
            <div style="width:100px;padding-right:20px; float:left">Email Subject</div><div><asp:Literal ID="lblEmailSubject" runat="server"></asp:Literal></div>
         </div>
         <br />  
         <div style="width:100%">       
            <asp:Literal ID="lblEmailBody" runat="server"></asp:Literal>         
         </div>       
    </div>
```

> But when I refresh the dialog displays even though it is not supposed
>   to display.
>
> I understand there is an autoOpen attribute which can be
>   set to false.
>
> I cannot use it as due to the body being created on
>   server side and post back happening the dialog does not get displayed when it is supposed
>   to show up if it is set to autoOpen : false.
>
> Question : Can you
>   tell me how I can make the Dialog never show up when the browser is
>   refreshed?

Comment: Are you saying you *never* want the dialog to appear when someone loads or refreshes the page - only when some action is taken client side ?

Comment: Never want the dialog to appear when the page is refreshed

Comment: Can you post *where* and how you call RegisterStartupScript ? Are you doing it in PageLoad ? You say "it is not supposed to display" but if you're not checking for IsPostback (for example) it will *always* display; RegisterStartupScript registers a script to be executed when the page has loaded, every time.

Comment: I am not doing it on Page load. I am doing it on button click server side code